How to save permanent data files in Ruffle?
I am curious as whether there is a proper way to save .sol or .swf game data to where you could use it with ruffle.rs. Currently, the save manager built into ruffle.rs does not work (in my experience).

This product has a Github. Have you checked there for known bugs?

Thank you, I will do that now.

It seems that there is not.

So is your issue how to bring .swf or other Flash content INTO Ruffle.rs, or how to save content already in the tool?

My issue is that using ruffle.rs's built in save editor DOESNT save my data when it should, I was wondering if there is a DIFFERENT way other than the save manager to have my game data saved. So how to save data already in the tool.
